# endothermic dissolution process

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry

Can anybody give me an example of an endothermic dissolution process, preferably one in which name of the substances involved are easy to remember. I have searched the Web thoroughly but could not find an example, only definitions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of an endothermic dissolution is dissolving potassium iodide in water.

Added: [Here](http://sites.chem.colostate.edu/diverdi/all_courses/CRC%20reference%20data/enthalpies%20of%20solution%20of%20electrolytes.pdf) is a table of Enthalpy of Solution for various compounds. Since this is the enthalpy of solution, some compounds will release energy when dissolve when the table indicates it would require energy to dissolve, and vice versa. If the number is negative, it is likely to be exothermic, and positive number are likely to be endothermic.

Comment: If $\Delta_{\text{sol}}H$ is negative, it is [exothermic](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E02269.html). If it is positive, it is [endothermic](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E02095.html). Both kinds of reactions can be overall [exergonic](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E02262.html) (spontanious), [endergonic](http://goldbook.iupac.org/E02091.html) (hindered) or in [equilibrium](http://goldbook.iupac.org/C01023.html).